# How migrate categorizes URLS in Ghost CMS?

Tags: jekyll, ghost-blog, ghost

Currently I'm using Jekyll with urls like

`article/<category>/<year>/<month>/<date>/<title>` and sometimes 
`article/<category>/<subcategory>/<year>/<month>/<date>/<title>`

How can I now move to Ghost (tryghost.org) CMS on my own server and keep those URLs or use redirects?

Comment: Have you considered trying a jekyll CMS instead?

Comment: @georgephillips which one? Currently I'm using Atom and just Markdown files. But for me the content generation is very slow (about 2 minutes jekyll build).

Comment: I am part of cloudcannon.com we have free support so we can assist you through the process. What version of Jekyll are you running? Jekyll has made big improvements across the last few months.